# HtmlService not working when passing parameter using <?= ?> in App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've done some App Script that will make a row and column into a nested array. The array is good, but when I used HtmlService to display it to HTML, the  script is not working. I tried couple of times and change the variable, but still not working. This is my first script in App Script and still learning.

**Code.gs**

```
function displayTableInHTML() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const absenteeismTab = ss.getSheetByName("EmailOutput");
  const absDetail = absenteeismTab.getRange(5,2,10000,6).getValues();
  const finalAbs = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < absDetail.length; x++) {
    if (absDetail[x][0].length !== 0){
      finalAbs.push(absDetail[x]);
    }
  };

  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  htmlTemplate.finalAbs = finalAbs;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?= finalAbs ?></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the html, it gave me an error.

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return displayTableInHTML();
}

function displayTableInHTML() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const absenteeismTab = ss.getSheetByName("EmailOutput");
  const absDetail = absenteeismTab.getRange(5,2,10000,6).getValues();
  const finalAbs = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < absDetail.length; x++) {
    if (absDetail[x][0].length !== 0){
      finalAbs.push(absDetail[x]);
    }
  };

  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  htmlTemplate.finalAbs = finalAbs;
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing the page? I doubt you miss a `doGet`

Comment: Can you show me the doGet code. The above is the only code that I wrote in my Code.gs

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: I copy paste your code, but same error message I got.

Comment: You have to [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) a new version everytime you change the code.

Comment: I tried to deploy the web app and re-open the googlesheet, but still not working. Same error,

Comment: Hey, Thank you. I actually review the code and figure out the problem. It's working now. Thanks again